# What's the simplest disapproving adjective a child would use?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

In order to translate a story that I wrote in my mothertongue, I need to use a specific word, which I might not know.

I would describe the word as: the most innocent disapproving term used by a toddler to express disapproval of things. Those things can be anything: a boy, a girl, a sweater, the weather... etc. This term is one of the earliest disapproving words that a child learns. And they stick to using it until their brains have developed more, and they have learnt more accurate words.

What I am particularly thinking about is the following scene: A little girl, does not like playing with a certain boy (it might be because he once mistreated her). Now she sees him. And to express her disapproval, would she say: 'Stupid boy' and turn away. Or would she say something different? And the usage of the word is very innocent.

I'm certain, the term differs from child to child. The thing is, I have no idea what an example might be. The word has to be an adjective, would 'stupid' be appropriate?

Comment: Can you add a sentence to the post? Will they call the item this wordor can it be a response like, "Hmph..."?

Comment: The earliest disapproving word that a child learns is probably "No!".

Comment: 'No' is not suitable, no child would say "no bicycle!" to express disapproval of a bicycle that the child has just fallen off.

The word has to be an adjective, a synonym of 'stupid'.

Comment: Probably something "poop" related. Even Koko used it to insult trainers she was mad at.

Comment: @Elias You may underestimate the lack of grammatical usage a child has. I know plenty of children who would say "no bicycle", not caring about it's grammatical validity one bit. What age range are we talking about here?

Comment: I am grateful to all of your contributions. The age is between 1 & 2 years old. I think this question would be easy for a parent to figure out..

Comment: What I am particularly thinking about is the following scene: A little girl, does not like playing with a certain boy (it might be because he once mistreated her). Now she sees him. And to express her disapproval, would she say: 'stupid boy' and turn away. Or would she say something different? And the usage of the word is very innocent.

Comment: These sentences are correct, and they might be used by a child. But they are not what I'm looking for. The word has to be an adjective, and it is an innocent word. Thank you.

Comment: *Horrible*, *bad*, *naughty* boy ...

Comment: The three words are correct. But I'm looking for something that may be used only by a child. I.e: the word would be understood as 'innocently disapproving' if used by a child, but it would sound completely odd if used by a grown up person. Whereas these three words might be used by both, a child and a grown up. The word I'm looking for might not even exist in the English language. But this is what I don't know.

Comment: Children don't have a language of their own, they learn it from their parents and others. They just have a smaller, simpler vocabulary. I think *bad* would be the word they're likely to use for lots of things. It wouldn't always sound odd for an adult, although in some cases it would sound simplistic.

Comment: I am grateful, thank you. Let's say for now that 'bad' is the word I'm seeking. If I learn something new in the future, I will update the post here. Thank you.

Comment: In my experience it's "No!" or "I dohn wanna!"

Comment: "Yucky" (or just "yuck") is a classic AmE toddler-disapproval term. There's even a YouTube meme of toddler girls expounding on the theme ["boys are yucky"](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=boys+are+yucky).

Answer (score 1):

As Hellion so rightly said, the earliest disapproving word that a child might use is prolly 'No'; failing that, prolly 'Not.'

The word 'stupid' is so unlikely to be in any way appropriate, we should rule it out completely.

Fairly obviously, the most innocent disapproving term used by a toddler to express anything you care to mention does not differ from child to child and to the extent that it could, it would not meet your definition.

So, are you actually looking for 'the most innocent disapproving term used by a toddler to express disapproval' or something else, please?